# Cannot prevent special characters ¥ € in Input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-mobile

I am working in jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap for Android and iPhone.
Currently am facing an issue that ; Some times some characters are entering in text-box while typing(**Its only happening in Mobile Devices!! not in Computer or Emulator**). But in its KeyPress event I prevent all the special characters. but 2-3 special characters are entering unexpectedly while typing.

I prevent all the special characters but when I type some numbers and suddenly type  **¥** or  **€** that will be enter in the text-box unexpectedly. But when I press that key again it will not enter.

My testing team raise it as a big issue.. and I tried lot to resolve this issue. but still this problem remains.. I think its a small issue.. but I takes my lot f valuable time.

My code is ;

```
('#testkeycode').live('keypress', function(){preventSpacedash(event)});
```

and its Function is ;

```
function preventSpacedash(event)
{    
var key = event.charCode ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;  
$(this).innerHTML = key;

if (key == 8364)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
else if (key == 8361)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
} 
else if (key == 163)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
else if ((key >= 32 && key <= 47))
{
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
else if ((key >= 58 && key <= 64))
{
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
else if ((key >= 91 && key <= 96))
{
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
else if ((key >= 123 && key <= 255))
{
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you logged the value you are getting for those characters in `key`?